# mutliline regex concatenation

Tags: regex, perl, awk, sed, grep

I have a tough one here which I am struggling with. It involves a case of multiline search-replace and/or concatenation situation. 
Here is my input text:

```
//                                                                                                            
import tset flash_read, flash_writ;
vector  ( $tset     , (XMOSI, XMISO, XSCLK, XSTRMSTRT, XSTRMSCLK, XSTRMCKEN, XXTALIN, XXTALCPUEN, XHVREGON, XFDRESET, XGLDATA5, XGLDATA4, XGLDATA3, XGLDATA2, XGLDATA1, XGLDATA0):H, (XSTRMD3, XSTRMD2, XSTRMD1, XSTRMD0, XNSS3, XNSS2, XNSS1, XNSS0):H, XTECLOCK, XRXDATA, XRXENABLE, XTXDATA, XTXENABLE, XNRESET, XTCK, XTMS, XTDI, XTDO, XNTRST)
{
repeat 2 
 > flash_writ X0X00X0XXXXXXXXX 0000XXXX X 0 L X X 0 1 0 0 X 0; // XNTRST
repeat 9 
 > flash_writ X0X00X0XXXXXXXXX 0000XXXX X 0 L X X 0 1 1 0 X 1; // Test Logic Reset
 > flash_writ X0X00X0XXXXXXXXX 0000XXXX X 0 L X X 0 1 0 0 X 1; // Run Test Idle
repeat 2 
 > flash_writ X0X00X0XXXXXXXXX 0000XXXX X 0 L X X 0 1 1 0 X 1; // Select IR
```

My desired output format is this:

```
//                                                                                                            
import tset flash_read, flash_writ;
vector  ( $tset     , (XMOSI, XMISO, XSCLK, XSTRMSTRT, XSTRMSCLK, XSTRMCKEN, XXTALIN, XXTALCPUEN, XHVREGON, XFDRESET, XGLDATA5, XGLDATA4, XGLDATA3, XGLDATA2, XGLDATA1, XGLDATA0):H, (XSTRMD3, XSTRMD2, XSTRMD1, XSTRMD0, XNSS3, XNSS2, XNSS1, XNSS0):H, XTECLOCK, XRXDATA, XRXENABLE, XTXDATA, XTXENABLE, XNRESET, XTCK, XTMS, XTDI, XTDO, XNTRST)
{
repeat 2              > flash_writ X0X00X0XXXXXXXXX 0000XXXX X 0 L X X 0 1 0 0 X 0; // XNTRST
repeat 9              > flash_writ X0X00X0XXXXXXXXX 0000XXXX X 0 L X X 0 1 1 0 X 1; // Test Logic Reset
                      > flash_writ X0X00X0XXXXXXXXX 0000XXXX X 0 L X X 0 1 0 0 X 1; // Run Test Idle
repeat 2              > flash_writ X0X00X0XXXXXXXXX 0000XXXX X 0 L X X 0 1 1 0 X 1; // Select IR
```

I am looking for a unix one liner that would search for lines that contain repeat in the input text and replace the new line character at the end of repeat count with a space such that the end outcome looks like the repeat line being concatenated with its next line as illustrated in the output text with the indicated number of white spaces.

For lines that do not contain a repeat count, it is just a matter of pushing the commencement of the line to as many spaces as illustrated in the output text.

Some of the areas where I have explored to accomplish this but with futile finishes are 
(1) Sed with usage of branch labels, N, pattern space
(2) AWK with changing the RS
(3) Perl with s/// and multiline flag turned on

Granted that this could be done with nested regex if conditions in a full-fledged perl or python script but I am looking for a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

In `perl`:

```
perl -0777 -lne 's/^(repeat[ ]+\d+)\s+/\1\t/mg; s/^[ ]*>/\t\t>/mg; print' file 
//                                                                                                            
import tset flash_read, flash_writ;
vector  (      , (XMOSI, XMISO, XSCLK, XSTRMSTRT, XSTRMSCLK, XSTRMCKEN, XXTALIN, XXTALCPUEN, XHVREGON, XFDRESET, XGLDATA5, XGLDATA4, XGLDATA3, XGLDATA2, XGLDATA1, XGLDATA0):H, (XSTRMD3, XSTRMD2, XSTRMD1, XSTRMD0, XNSS3, XNSS2, XNSS1, XNSS0):H, XTECLOCK, XRXDATA, XRXENABLE, XTXDATA, XTXENABLE, XNRESET, XTCK, XTMS, XTDI, XTDO, XNTRST)
{
repeat 2    > flash_writ X0X00X0XXXXXXXXX 0000XXXX X 0 L X X 0 1 0 0 X 0; // XNTRST
repeat 9    > flash_writ X0X00X0XXXXXXXXX 0000XXXX X 0 L X X 0 1 1 0 X 1; // Test Logic Reset
            > flash_writ X0X00X0XXXXXXXXX 0000XXXX X 0 L X X 0 1 0 0 X 1; // Run Test Idle
repeat 2    > flash_writ X0X00X0XXXXXXXXX 0000XXXX X 0 L X X 0 1 1 0 X 1; // Select IR
```

Or, you can also do:

```
perl -0777 -lpe 's/^(repeat[ ]+\d+)\s+/\1\t/mg; s/^[ ]*>/\t\t>/mg;' file
```

You may need to play with how many `\t` in the second substitution, but you get the idea.

---

Ed's `awk` is brilliant. You can also do something like that in `perl`:

```
perl -lne ' if (/^repeat[\h]+\d+/) {$ll=$_; next} 
            if (/^\h+>/) {$_=sprintf("%-21s%s",$ll,$_);$ll="";}
            print' file
```

Comment: dawg, thank you for taking a stab at this. Actually your idea worked. Just had to make a few minor tweaks. The final working expression for me was perl -0777 -lne 's/^[ ]*(>)/\t\t$1/mg; s/^(repeat[ ]+\d+)\s+/$1\t/mg; print' inputfile | tee output file

Comment: I tried to add a -i switch after the perl -0777 to try to see if the changes can be applied in-place but it did not seem to work. For now, I am okay with redirecting the output stream to a new file but curious to know as to why in-place did not work.

Comment: @user3791998 the `-i` option accepts an optional argument for backup purposes.. so if you tried the option combining with other options, it wouldn't work... try `perl -i -0777 -lne '...'`

Comment: Hi Sundeep, thank you for your tip. yes I was trying to do a perl -0777 -ilne and it did not work. After changing it to perl -i -0777 -lne, it worked well. Also perl -0777 -i -lne worked. So the position of the -i switch in the command did not matter as long as this switch wasn't combined with the others.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '
    /^repeat/ { pfx = $0; next }
    /^ >/     { $0 = sprintf("%-21s%s", pfx, $0); pfx="" }
    { print }
' file
//
import tset flash_read, flash_writ;
vector  ( $tset     , (XMOSI, XMISO, XSCLK, XSTRMSTRT, XSTRMSCLK, XSTRMCKEN, XXTALIN, XXTALCPUEN, XHVREGON, XFDRESET, XGLDATA5, XGLDATA4, XGLDATA3, XGLDATA2, XGLDATA1, XGLDATA0):H, (XSTRMD3, XSTRMD2, XSTRMD1, XSTRMD0, XNSS3, XNSS2, XNSS1, XNSS0):H, XTECLOCK, XRXDATA, XRXENABLE, XTXDATA, XTXENABLE, XNRESET, XTCK, XTMS, XTDI, XTDO, XNTRST)
{
repeat 2              > flash_writ X0X00X0XXXXXXXXX 0000XXXX X 0 L X X 0 1 0 0 X 0; // XNTRST
repeat 9              > flash_writ X0X00X0XXXXXXXXX 0000XXXX X 0 L X X 0 1 1 0 X 1; // Test Logic Reset
                      > flash_writ X0X00X0XXXXXXXXX 0000XXXX X 0 L X X 0 1 0 0 X 1; // Run Test Idle
repeat 2              > flash_writ X0X00X0XXXXXXXXX 0000XXXX X 0 L X X 0 1 1 0 X 1; // Select IR
```

or if you prefer brevity over clarity:

```
awk '/^repeat/{p=$0;next} /^ >/{$0=sprintf("%-21s",p)$0;p=""} 1' file
```

and if you want "in place" editing then use GNU awk:

```
awk -i inplace '/^repeat/{p=$0;next} /^ >/{$0=sprintf("%-21s",p)$0;p=""} 1' file
```

Comment: Hi Ed, thank you for your answer. The solutions are excellent. After looking at the 3 solutions, I prefer the first one due to the clarity. However, a little bit of explanation on what the 3 lines of awk do would have helped save me some time to decode them or perhaps for some other awk newbie who may try to discern this to apply these ideas for his/her specific use-cases.

Comment: So my understanding is as follows: (1) In the first line, awk looks for a line beginning with repeat and if it finds such a line, it stores it in a variable called pfx and then moves on to the next line. (2) In the second line, if the immediate next line beginning with > is found, then the content stored in pfx is placed in a 22 character length left justified format string followed by the content of the current line. Then the value of the pfx variable is reset to "" so that for all other lines the > prints out after a left justification of 22 spaces.

Comment: (3) Third line of the awk program just says print all the lines by satisfying the above 2 conditions.

Comment: RIght and I didn't comment the code as it's simple enough for any newbie to understand with just a little thought and they learn more about awk from researching and thinking about that than if they were spoonfed just this answer. You can always add "print"s to the script see see what values the variables have too if there's anything you don't understand.